# Dropzone error with URL preventing image upload

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms, dropzone

So I have been trying to follow this tutorial: https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-5-5-and-dropzone-js-uploading-images-with-removal-links/
to enable my form to upload multiple photos using Dropzone js. So I altered my existing form to resemble the form in the tutorial and added in the config js file and the dropzone file to my php page. But I am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: No URL provided. at new Dropzone.

I was looking at other questions of the same problem and I have my config loaded right after the dropzone js but it still doesn't work and as far as I can see I do have a destination for my form as you can see in the provided code. Can anyone help me out with this please?

This is my form opening:

```
{!! Form::open([
    'method'=>'POST', 
    'class'=>'dropzone', 
    'id'=>'mydropzone', 
    'action'=> 'AdminPostsController@store',
    'files'=>true
]) !!}
```

As you can see I have a destination of AdminPostsController@store set for it.

As a result of this error when I submit the form the image files don't go through. In the tutorial they show that the images get received via:

```
$photos = $request->file('file');
```

but my `$request->file` is empty.

Comment: If `$request->file` is empty, you probably need to add an `enctype` of `multipart/form-data` to your `<form>` element. I'm not sure if `'files' => true` is supposed to be doing that, but I generally don't use the `Form` helper.

Comment: Please show use what the actual HTML code for the `<form>` header looks like.

Comment: Isn't that what this is: 
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data", 'class'=>'dropzone', 'id'=>'mydropzone', 'action'=> 'AdminPostsController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}
I had it in my original question